# Dealing with delimiters in column entries pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a large CSV file and there are a few entries in one of the columns that use a comma within the entry. For example, one entry might read something like `"\"a,bcde\""`, another entry might read something like `"\"abcde\""`, and another entry will read like `<unknown>`. So, when the entry is known (sometimes it's also just an empty string, e.g., `""`), the pattern is clear in that it starts with `"\"` and ends with `\""`, and everything inside these markers is the entry I want.

When I try to pull this into pandas, I get an error when the entry with the comma is pulled in (`Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 32 fields in line 24193, saw 33`). So I'm not sure what to do with this. Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a max up of two methods, the first is a multiple replace and the second is reading the csv into memory doing the replaces you need and then putting it into pandas.  It will be slow for large files.

```
import re
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

def multiple_replace(dict, text):
    # Create a regular expression  from the dictionary keys
    regex = re.compile("(%s)" % "|".join(map(re.escape, dict.keys())))

    # For each match, look-up corresponding value in dictionary
    return regex.sub(lambda mo: dict[mo.string[mo.start():mo.end()]], text) 

dict = {
    '"\"' : '"',
    '\""' : '"',
} 

with open('file.csv') as file:
    for line in file:
    lines = [multiple_replace(dict, line) for line in file]
    

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('\n'.join(lines)))
```

Comment: This is working sometimes, but I get an error at some point in the iteration: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 7933: character maps to <undefined>`. I'm not sure why this happens, and I can't seem to get a traceback to the exact line that triggered this error. My code for this is: `with open(files[0], 'r') as file: lines = [multiple_replace(d, l) for l in file]`. At this point, I'm just using `error_bad_lines=False` within pandas to just skip these lines...

Comment: This means that you have a non Unicode character in one of the files

Comment: So the solution is mainly your solution, but with a couple of tweeks. I'll put the whole thing below, but accept yours as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what finally worked for me, given that some of the encoding was not utf-8.

```
import re
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

def multiple_replace(d, text):
    # Create a regular expression  from the dictionary keys
    regex = re.compile("(%s)" % "|".join(map(re.escape, d.keys())))

    # For each match, look-up corresponding value in dictionary
    return regex.sub(lambda mo: d[mo.string[mo.start():mo.end()]], text) 

d = {
    '"\\"' : '"',
    '\\""' : '"',
    }


with open("file.csv", 'r', errors='ignore') as f: #ignore errors to deal with non-utf-8 encoding
    lines = [multiple_replace(d, l) for l in f]

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(''.join(lines)))
```